# detect if scrollview has reached the bottom titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I need to detect if the scrollview has reached the bottom when the user scrolls down so i can load more data in tho it? How can i do this the best way? i have tried:

```
scrollView.addEventListener("scrollend", function(e){
    b = 10;
    AddList();
});
```

But i't does not solve my problem because it loads data into the scroll when the scrollview stops scrolling and only works in IOS and i need it to work also in android.

I'm not using the alloy folder

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the infinite scroll (facebook timeline, instagram feed, etc;) Without a doubt this module works best for iOS & Android, plus the documentation is clear. Works with Alloy & Classic Titanium: https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.infiniteScroll